# Which approach is the best when we want to deploy two websites on the same aws EC2 instance?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

Which approach is the best when we want to deploy two websites on the same aws EC2 instance?

- two separate Docker container each consists a django project
- one Docker container consists of two separate django project

if the two of them are basic django-cms projects and we know they wont expand in future (nor python packages dependency neither vertical or horizontal scaling)

My purpose is to deploy 10 low-traffic django-cms websites on the same aws ec2 instance...

P.S.
I'm using Elastic Beanstalk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure the answer is "It depends" but I believe the whole reason for using Docker is to isolate your environment, and gain flexibility.

So what happens if one project uses a bunch of python packages, and the other uses a bunch of other packages. Worse, what if any of them conflict with each other. Forget about a case where a package may require some changes to the OS.

And what happens if you need to scale and maybe move to two separate EC2 instances?

I also believe you want to isolate changes to one project when fixing the other, rather than been forced to always re-deploy both projects together.

In both of this cases, **using two separate docker containers** is safer, and more flexible/powerful.

Answer (score 0):

What is easier to maintain for you?

- Handling software updates?
- Redeploying sources?
- Reconfiguring each app?

I like separation and therefore I would define two separate Docker container but then your in need of a load balancer in front because both containers will need a separate port. The load balancer itself will need either subdomains or domains in order to separate requests for each container.

Examples:

- www.app1.com -> container1
- www.app2.com -> container2

Example with subdomain:

- app1.example.com -> container1
- app2.example.com -> container2

Possible load balancers:

- Apache on same EC2 instance.
- Nginx on same EC2 instance. I have an example container here: [blacklabelops/nginx](https://hub.docker.com/r/blacklabelops/nginx/)
- AmazonWS Load Balancer included in EC2.

Benefit from load balancer in front:

- Minimize Downtime -> Both applications can have an update without any downtime for the other.
- Enables High Availability -> Possible Blue White Deployments of one app. Depends on your app.

You can circumvent this complexity by using your example tutorial where everything is inside the same container. You will also have all the configuration details in the same place.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know why you don't choose the simpler option:

1. 2 x Python virtual environments; one for each django application.
2. 2 x uwsgi master processes, one for each django application
3. 1 x supervisor process to manage the uwsgi threads
4. 1 x nginx mapped correctly for both applications.

This is how things were setup and have been working for years before docker became everyone's favorite toy.